# Send long SMS messages sequentially with delay

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast

I have a situation where I want to send a long message (around 600 characters) to approximately 10 people. The problem message of 600 characters means 4 SMS so the final count comes to 40 messages.

I would usually do something like this for long messages:

```
String phoneNo = etPhoneNo.getText().toString();
String msg = etMsg.getText().toString();
try {
  SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
  ArrayList<String> msgArray = smsManager.divideMessage(msg);

  smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNo, null, msgArray, null, null);
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

} catch (Exception ex) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

The problem is of course if I trigger this 10 times, I will send 40 messages at the same time. I don't want that as there is limitation on sms messages. On KitKat it's 30 messages in 30 minutes.

How can I accomplish to send next message 30-40 seconds after previous message was successfully sent? My goal is to receive some confirmation that message is sent and then start sending another message.

Answer (score 0):

You possibly need a [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to send message every few second (in case your app is in background). If your app is always in foreground, you can use thread and `timertask`.

If you want to make sure that sms is sent successfully, you may refer to this post:
[Java android, how to know if a sms is successfully sent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14582801/java-android-how-to-know-if-a-sms-is-successfully-sent)

Comment: Thanks but I have a feeling there is still a problem with large messages. In theory user can write a message which is long like 6 messages and for that I would need to have a delay of 3 minutes between those big messages. It's hard to know a correct delay.

Comment: Oh, I don't know that! Any clue for the information about 3 mins delay of big SMS?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is Threading technique. Make a thread that sleep with given delay.

**Aproach**

```
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // put code to execute send SMS here

            try {
                // and make delay 5 second
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    // execute thread
    thread.start();
```